# Gcloud kms error: crypto_key_version.state: DESTROYED, but ENABLED is required

Tags: gcloud, secret-key

I'm trying to encrypt a secret with google kms like this:

```
gcloud kms encrypt --ciphertext-file=encrypted_secret --plaintext-file=secret --key very_secret_key --keyring=very_secret_ring --location=very secret_location
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.kms.encrypt) FAILED_PRECONDITION: The request cannot be fulfilled. Resource projects/amazing_project/locations/very_secret_location/keyRings/very_secret_keyring/cryptoKeys/very_secret_key/cryptoKeyVersions/1 has crypto_key_version.state: DESTROYED, but ENABLED is required.
```

Any input much appreciated since I can't find anything related to this issue in GCP docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error stands for key material not being stored anymore. Use another key or update this one
More info here: 
https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.kms.v1#google.cloud.kms.v1.CryptoKeyVersion.CryptoKeyVersionState